# How to extend d3 histogram axis without manually fiddling with the svg path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble remembering how to extend the horizontal axis of a histogram to the last+1 bin in d3.

Here's what I've got - note the scale doesn't extend to the last bin + 1, so the final bars appear "off the scale":
[image: histogram]

```
this.xAxis = this.svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "xaxis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));
```

I remember there was a property or a method that you could chain to the end of the axis call to get the axis to display correctly:

- without manually fiddling with the domain function, and
- without manually fiddling with how the svg path is drawn.

I can't seem to find anything in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band-scales) though. Anyone know the method or property I'm talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it, but changing the scale object of the axis should work. Therefore, you have to store the scale separately and then changing the range:

```
scale.range([1,16]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remembered. It was [.nice()](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice)